# Closed-form formula for $E_{x}[\max(u^\top x,0)\max(v^\top x ,0)]$ where $u,v$ are fixed vectors in $\mathbb R^d$ and $x$ is uniform on the sphere

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-probability

Let $x$ be uniformly distributed on the unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^d$ and let $u,v$ be fixed nonparallel vectors in $\mathbb R^d$

> **Question.** Is there a closed-form formula for $f(u,v) := \mathbb E_{x}[\max(u^\top x,0)\max(v^\top x ,0)]$ ?

Due to rotationational symmetry of the distribution of $x$, my guess is that $f(u,v)$ admits a simple expression in terms of the angle between $u$ and $v$.

Comment: On second thought, one should be able to project $x$ onto the two-dimensional subspace spanned by $u$ and $v$. Let $P$ be the orthogonal projector onto this plane, and let $c := Px$, $a := Pu$, and $b := Pv$. Then $f(u,v) = \mathbb E_c [(a^\top c)_+(b^\top c)_+]$. Hopefully, this is easier to simplify.

Comment: Is there a specific context for this question?

Comment: Sure. It arises from analyzing a neural network with the synaptic weights $x$ initialized from at random. $(u^\top x)_+$ is the activation of the neuron when presented th an input $u \in \mathbb R^d$ (e.g and image with $d$ pixels). Thus $f(u,v)$ is the correlation coefficient of the activations on inputs $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can look at normalized vector: $f(u,v) = ||u||\cdot||v||\cdot f\Big(\frac{u}{||u||}, \frac{v}{||v||}\Big)$, so let us assume that $u$ and $v$ are normalized. Then we can write $v = \rho u + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} u_2$ with $\rho = (u^Tv) \in [-1,1]$ and $u_2$ unitary orthogonal to $u$, and then complete $(u,u_2)$ into an orthogonal base of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and look at coordinates $(x_1,...,x_d)$ in that base.

---

Initial remarks:

- the volume $V_k$ of the unit ball $B_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ is [$V_k = \frac{\pi^{k/2}}{\Gamma(k/2+1)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball)
- the density of $(R, \theta)$ s.t. $(R\cos(\theta), R\sin(\theta))$ is uniformly distributed on the unit disk is $\frac{R}{\pi}dRd\theta$

---

\begin{align*}
f(u,v) & = \displaystyle{\int_{B_d}} \max(x_1, 0)\max\big(\rho x_1 + (1-\rho)x_2, 0\big)\frac{dx_1...dx_d}{V_d} \\
 & = \displaystyle{\int_0^1} \displaystyle{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}} \max(r\cos(\theta),0)\max(\rho r\cos(\theta) + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}r\sin(\theta),0) \cdot r d\theta \cdot \frac{(1-r^2)^{d/2-1} V_{d-2}}{V_d} dr \\
 & = \displaystyle{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}} \max(\cos(\theta),0)\max(\rho \cos(\theta) + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sin(\theta), 0)d\theta \cdot \displaystyle{\int_0^1} r^3 (1-r^2)^{d/2-1} dr \cdot \frac{d}{2 \pi}\end{align*}

where $(1-r^2)^{(d-2)/2} V_{d-2}$ stems from the integration over $x_3,...,x_d$ with $(x_1,...,x_d) \in B_d$ and $x_1^2+x_2^2=r^2$, and on the last line we use our formula for $V_d$ and $V_{d-2}$.

Let us compute the two integrals. The second one is simpler:

$$\displaystyle{\int_0^1} r^3(1-r^2)^{d/2-1}dr = \Big[-\frac{(1-r^2)^{d/2} \big(2 + dr^2\big)}{d(d+2)}\Big]_0^1 = \frac{2}{d(d+2)}$$

In the first integral, the integrand is non zero iff $\theta \in \big[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\big]$ and $\rho \cos(\theta) + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sin(\theta)$, so iff $\theta \in \big[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\big]$ or $-\mbox{Arctan}\big(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\big) \le \theta \le 0$. Let us denote $\theta_0 = -\mbox{Arctan}\big(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\big)$.

Thus the integral is \begin{align*} \displaystyle{\int_{\theta_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \rho \cos(\theta)^2 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)d\theta & = \frac{2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\cos(\theta_0)^2 + \rho(\pi - 2\theta_0 - \sin(2\theta_0))}{4} \\
 & = \frac{\rho \pi + 2\sqrt{1-\rho^2} + 2\rho \mbox{Arctan}\big(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\big)}{4} \end{align*}

To conclude, $$\mbox{with } \rho = \frac{(u^Tv)}{\sqrt{(u^Tu)(v^Tv)}}, \quad f(u,v) = \sqrt{(u^Tu)(v^Tv)} \cdot \frac{\rho \pi + 2\sqrt{1-\rho^2} + 2\rho \mbox{Arctan}\big(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\big)}{4(d+2)\pi}.$$

---

Nota bene: if it can make you any less dubious about the previous computations, I made some Python simulations with $d=2$ and $d=3$ and Monte-Carlo simulations coincide with the theoretical formula.

Comment: Great. Thanks. The $1/d$ scaling matches intuition.

Comment: Sounds interesting, what is the reasoning behind your intuition? (and is it only about the fact that $f(u,v)$ decreases ad $d$ increases, or is the exact scaling $\frac{1}{d}$ something you were expecting?)

Comment: It's about the exact $1/d$ scaling. Here is the reasoning. By rotational invariance, $f(u,u) = E[\max(u^\top x,0)^2] = \|u\|^2 E[\max(x_1,0)^2] \approx \|u\|^2 E[\max(\mathcal N(0,1/d),0)^2] = \dfrac{\|u\|^2}{2d}$, where I've used the fact that if $d$ is large and $x$ is uniform on the $(d-1)$-dimensional unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^d$, then $P(x_1 \le  t) = \Phi(\sqrt{d} t) + \mathcal O(1/d)$. A similar argument should work for $f(u,v)$ when$u$ and $v$ are not parallel, by projecting onto the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer.** *This is just to simplify @chamd's answer and make it more "recognisable", and draw some links to standard machine-learning theory terminology (kernel methods).*

So, @chamd's has proved that $f(u,v) = \|u\|\|v\|\phi(\frac{u^\top v}{\|u\|\|v\|})$,

where $\phi:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ is defined by $\phi(t) = \dfrac{\pi t + 2 \sqrt{1-t^2} + 2t\arctan(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}})}{4(d+2)\pi}$.

We're in the $uv$-plane and $t \in [-1,1]$ is nothing but the height a point  $P=(\sqrt{1-t^2},t)$ on the unit circle in this plane. The angle pointint the positive $v$ axis ray $OP$ is given by $\theta = \arctan(t/\sqrt{1-t^2})$. By inspecting the geometry of the situation (basically drawing a diagram on a piece of paper...), it is evident that we can rewrite $\theta = \arccos(t)$. Thus, we can rewrite the function $\phi$ as

$$
\begin{split}
\phi(t) &= \dfrac{\pi t + 2 \sqrt{1-t^2} + 2t\arccos(t)}{4\pi} = \frac{t(\pi + 2\arccos(t)) + 2\sqrt{1-t^2}}{4\pi}\\
&= \frac{t(\pi - \arccos(t)) + \sqrt{1-t^2}}{2\pi}\\
&= \frac{t\arccos(-t) + \sqrt{1-t^2}}{2\pi}.
\end{split}
$$

Now is the time for the harvest.

- The second line in the above display is nothing but the main ingredient in so-called [arc-cosine kernels](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.3712.pdf): these is the kernel for the Gaussian process which emerges when one looks at infinite-width limit of neural networks with ReLU activations, width the weights initialized at random. More precisely, $f \sim (1/(d+2))K_{ReLU}$.
- Noting that, for large $d$, (1) The individual coordinates of a point sampled uniformy at random the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^d$ is roughly distributed as $\mathcal N(0,1/d)$, and (2) The pairwise correlations of the coordinates is approximately zero, we could have expected $f(u,v)$ to be approximately equal to $\mathbb E_{z \sim \mathcal N(0,1/d)}[\max(u^\top z, 0)\max(v^\top z, 0)] = (1/d)K_{ReLU}(u,v)$.